# Foods that inhibit BACE1 protein

Tags: diet, mental-health, alzheimers, nootropic-smart-drugs

It is said that BACE1 causes mental illness such as alzheimers. What foods or drugs will inhibit the production of BACE1?

Comment: Welcome to Health, Ivas! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. A reminder: Personalised medical advice is off-topic here. What havs your previous research revealed to you so far, please link to it, if possible. You may improve your question (to comply with site guidelines) with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extension trial [A Study of Lanabecestat (LY3314814) in Early Alzheimer's Disease Dementia](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT02972658) is currently in progress but is not expected to complete until 9/2020.

Other investigational drugs have [ceased development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-secretase_1#BACE_inhibitors). A paper [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.neulet.2017.11.052) suggests chitosan polysaccharides have in vitro activity as inhibitors.